# File decriptors and socket connections

Tags: c++, c, sockets, unix, network-programming

I am trying to understand how are file descriptors related to sockets. As per my understanding, you listen on a particular file descriptor, once a connection comes in , you accept it , which returns you another file descriptor ( 2 in all ) and you use this 2nd descriptor to send/recv data.

The strange behaviour i am observing is that after accept , i have 3 file descriptors instead of two.... and i am not sure why is this the case....

I am either using lsof or /proc/pid to observe the increase in number of fd's.

ps : these are af_unix sockets.

EDIT : CODE

Here is the code to create the scoket.

```
   int s, s2,  len;
    socklen_t t;
    struct sockaddr_un local, remote;

    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
            syslog(LOG_ERR,"Failed to create a socket");
            exit(1);
    }
    int flags =  fcntl(s, F_GETFD);
    if (flags == -1)
    {
            syslog(LOG_ERR,"Failed to get socket flags");
            exit(1);
    }

    flags |= FD_CLOEXEC;

    if (fcntl(s, F_SETFD, flags) == -1)
    {
            syslog(LOG_ERR,"Failed to set socket flags");
            exit(1);
    }

    local.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(local.sun_path, SOCK_PATH.c_str());

    unlink(local.sun_path);
    len = strlen(local.sun_path) + sizeof(local.sun_family);

    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&local, len) == -1)
    {
            syslog(LOG_ERR,"Failed to bind socket");
            exit(1);
    }


    if (listen(s, 5) == -1)
    {
            syslog(LOG_ERR,"Failed to listen at socket");
            exit(1);
    }
```

Code where connection is accepted

> ```
>     while (1)
>     {
>             stat =0;
>             execReturn=0;
>             t = len;
>             read_fds = master;
>             if (select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, &tv) != -1)
>             {
>                     if(FD_ISSET(s,&read_fds))
>                     {
>                             //Accept new connection
>                             //fork child -> fork grand child
>                             //child will return value back
>
>                             if ((s2 = accept(s, (struct sockaddr*)&remote, &t)) == -1)
>                             {
>                                     syslog(LOG_ERR,"Failed to acceptconnection  at socket");
>                                     exit(1);
>                             }
> ```

I am stepping through gdb and exactly after accept , the fd's become 3. The OS is fedora core 13.

The reason i need to validate this is i do not want my process to hold on to FD's ; since being a daemon over time it may walk the system into a corner...

This did seem odd behaviour. After closing the accepted connection i am still left with two fd's .
i.e. one for listen and one ghost fd... Whats even more strange is that even if 10 connections are made , only one ghost fd remains at the end of all of them closing....

It does sound like OS specific implementation..

Cheers!

Comment: Is there a small snippet of code you have that reproduces this problem?

Comment: Hard to say without more code and evidence of the symptoms you report.  (Do you syslog right after the accept?  That'd burn an fd.)  However, `lsof` and `/proc/$pid/fd` should let you determine whether that unexpected fd is a duplicate of the bound or accepted socket...

Comment: it sounds like gdb is up to something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your extra file descriptor is most likely related to `syslog`.  Syslog has to open a socket to the syslogd to report messages.  Unless you explicitly call `openlog` this socket is opened upon the first call to `syslog`, and since you aren't calling `syslog` until you have an error you are most likely observing `syslog`'s side effects.

Comment: Exactly the problem. Thanks ! :))

Comment: Also : There is a explicit call to openlog , yet the socket appears after the first syslog call.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to debug this sort of issues is to run your app under the [`strace(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) utility. Check what system calls are made, what the parameters and return values are, and correlate that to file descriptors used.

Answer (score 0):

More code please.

But I am guessing that you are looking at the OS implementation of the socket.
It probably uses one file descriptor for reading and the other for writing (but that is a guess).

What does it matter to you what the OS is doing in `/proc/pid` the stuff in there is not really there for your direct usage.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in that it's two. You must be confusing the third with something else.

Without more information it's hard to help.